# Laravel Custom Queue Not Respecting retry_after

Tags: php, laravel

I am having some trouble with a custom laravel queue connection/queue. This particular connection/queue is being used for jobs which may be anywhere from 5 minutes to 10 hours (large data aggregations and data rebuilds)

I have a supervisor conf defined as

```
[program:laravel-worker-extended]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --queue=refreshQueue,rebuildQueue --sleep=3 --timeout=86400 --tries=2 --delay=360
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/queue-worker.log
```

I have a queue connection defined as:

```
        'refreshQueue' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'refreshQueue',
            'retry_after' => 420,   // Retry after 7 minutes
        ],
```

I’m adding a job to the queue with a Command via:

```
AggregateData::dispatch()->onConnection('refreshQueue')->onQueue('refreshQueue');
```

When DatabaseQueue is constructed, retryAfter is 420 as defined. however here are my job logs:

```
[2020-01-22 18:25:37] local.INFO: BEGINNING AGGREGATION  
[2020-01-22 18:25:37] local.INFO: Aggregating data  
[2020-01-22 18:27:08] local.INFO: BEGINNING AGGREGATION  
[2020-01-22 18:27:08] local.ALERT: AGGREGATION FAILED: Aggregation in progress
```

Why does it continue to retry after 90 seconds when I explicitly tell it to retry after 420?

I’ve rebuilt my container, restarted the queue, and done about everything else I can to debug... and then waiting a while, I get this final log output:

```
[2020-01-22 18:25:37] local.INFO: BEGINNING AGGREGATION  
[2020-01-22 18:25:37] local.INFO: Aggregating data  
[2020-01-22 18:27:08] local.INFO: BEGINNING AGGREGATION  
[2020-01-22 18:27:08] local.ALERT: AGGREGATION FAILED: Aggregation in progress  
[2020-01-22 18:33:04] local.INFO: [COMPLETE] Aggregating data  
[2020-01-22 18:33:04] local.INFO: Queue job finishedIlluminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call
```

I can't quite grasp why the queue continues to retry the job after 90 seconds. Am I doing something wrong here?

Editing for some additional context here:

This method sets an `in_progress` flag when it begins, so that it cannot be run twice at the same exact time. The logs can be interpreted as:

`BEGINNING AGGREGATION`: First line in the `handle()` method of the job

`AGGREGATION FAILED: Aggregation in progress`: The `failed()` method of the job handles failures via exception. This line shows that it has both attempted the job *again*, and encountered the flag being set to `1` already meaning another job is processing currently. This flag gets reset to 0 when the job is complete or a different exception (not 'in-progress') is encountered.

`Queue job finishedIlluminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call` Is further debugging I added in the service provider to listen for queue complete events.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same job and the same queue that is running again after 90 seconds?

Comment: In debugging further, adjusting `numprocs` to 1 for this particular queue works, in that it doesn't retry while running. It seems that the queue is not 'locking' this process and other workers are attempting to pick it up while it is executing. It is indeed the same set of supervisor processes that are attempting to re-process this, as I've examined in htop.

Comment: Further debugging: When logging in `DatabaseQueue::getNextAvailableJob()`,  `$this->retryAfter` is set to 90 for some reason.. xDebug can't seem to attach to the queue workers, but on initial job creation I have breakpoint in that constructor and `$retryAfter` is the 420 I set in the `queue.php` config. I've cleared cache and restarted workers, but it's like Laravel is ignoring the settings.

Comment: A job itself can have a variable $retryAfter I think, is that set for you by any chance?

Comment: Setting a job-level `$retryAfter` does indeed work, however I don't want to require such granular control of these jobs. Setting that variable puts it into the `payload` in the `jobs` table, but I'd rather the default behavior work properly first before requiring param settings on the classes themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the issue here. In `queue.php` I was defining a **connection** `refreshQueue`. However, in my supervisor conf I was using:

```
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --queue=refreshQueue,rebuildQueue --sleep=3 --timeout=86400 --tries=2 --delay=360
```

as the command (`--queue`), where the command *should* have been:

```
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work refreshQueue --sleep=3 --timeout=86400 --tries=2 --delay=360
```

Note the lack of `--queue`. The **connection** has the `retry_after` defined, not the queue itself.

This is a valuable lesson in the difference of [connections vs queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#connections-vs-queues).

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do something with time timeout you're using. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts):

> The --timeout value should always be at least several seconds shorter than your retry_after configuration value. This will ensure that a worker processing a given job is always killed before the job is retried. If your --timeout option is longer than your retry_after configuration value, your jobs may be processed twice.

Comment: I originally had that issue when working with queues, but my timeout as of now is 86400s, and my jobs won't be running for longer than 5 hours, but the most frequent job has about a 5 minute runtime.